# CSS: remove padding created by scroll

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to build a UI similar to Apple Mail, when left bar has horizontal list of emails through which you can scroll. The problem is that when I add a scroll, it's creating an additional padding instead of being rendered on top of the content.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html style="height: 100%;">
<head>
<style>
.scrollable-list-item {
  padding: 1rem;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #cdcdcd;
}
.scrollable-list-item-active {
  background-color: #0069d9;
  color: white;
}
</style>
</head>
<body style="height: 100%; width: 100%; margin: 0">
  <div style="height: 100%; width: 100%; display: flex;">
      <div style="width: 200px; height: 100%; overflow-x: scroll; background-color: #efefef;">
          <div class="scrollable-list-item">scrollable list item</div>
          <div class="scrollable-list-item scrollable-list-item-active">scrollable list item</div>
          <div class="scrollable-list-item">scrollable list item</div>
          <div class="scrollable-list-item">scrollable list item</div>
          <div class="scrollable-list-item">scrollable list item</div>
          <div class="scrollable-list-item">scrollable list item</div>
          <div class="scrollable-list-item">scrollable list item</div>
          <div class="scrollable-list-item">scrollable list item</div>
          <div class="scrollable-list-item">scrollable list item</div>
          <div class="scrollable-list-item">scrollable list item</div>
          <div class="scrollable-list-item">scrollable list item</div>
          <div class="scrollable-list-item">scrollable list item</div>
          <div class="scrollable-list-item">scrollable list item</div>
          <div class="scrollable-list-item">scrollable list item</div>
          <div class="scrollable-list-item">scrollable list item</div>
          <div class="scrollable-list-item">scrollable list item</div>
          <div class="scrollable-list-item">scrollable list item</div>
          <div class="scrollable-list-item">scrollable list item</div>
          <div class="scrollable-list-item">scrollable list item</div>
          <div class="scrollable-list-item">scrollable list item</div>
          <div class="scrollable-list-item">scrollable list item</div>
          <div class="scrollable-list-item">scrollable list item</div>
          <div class="scrollable-list-item">scrollable list item</div>
          <div class="scrollable-list-item">scrollable list item</div>
          <div class="scrollable-list-item">scrollable list item</div>
          <div class="scrollable-list-item">scrollable list item</div>
          <div class="scrollable-list-item">scrollable list item</div>
          <div class="scrollable-list-item">scrollable list item</div>
      </div>
      <div>content</div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Without scroll:

[image]

With scroll:

[image]

What is the proper way to add scroll without adding a blank area around it? Thank you!

Comment: Add custom scrollbar plugin, style it to be `position: absolute`. Or create another fake scroll div that will auto-scroll original div with JS

Comment: Scroll style are rendered different in different browsers.
If you run your snippet in Firefox, you would not see extra padding rather a vertical section defined for scrollbar

Comment: @UtsavPatel screenshots are for Firefox on Ubuntu, I'd like it to work in all major OSes and browsers

Comment: So do you want the scrollbar to be visible?
Or are you okay with scrollbar being hidden?

I am using Firefox on mac, it is different from the snapshots you have posted

Comment: @UtsavPatel I'm ok with it behaving like on macOS, e.g. showing when you're scrolling or hover, but hidden otherwise

Comment: In Chrome for example there is no extra-padding with your code

Comment: All right, it seems that so far, the minimum code that would be close to what I want would be to add `scrollbar-width: none` by default and `scrollbar-width: thin` on hover. It has side-effects on hover (adding the padding), but is good enough for now. Ideal solution would be great to see.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can apply `scrollbar-width: none` to the container div.

This will hide the scrollbar altogether. You will be able to scroll.

Although the browser support for this property is fairly new.

You can read about it [here](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/s/scrollbar-width/)

Without a custom library the desired behaviour is not possible

```html
<!doctype html>
<html style="height: 100%;">
<head>
<style>
 .container {
   scrollbar-width: none;
  -ms-overflow-style: none;
  }
.scrollable-list-item {
  padding: 1rem;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #cdcdcd;
  
}
.scrollable-list-item-active {
  background-color: #0069d9;
  color: white;
}
</style>
</head>
<body style="height: 100%; width: 100%; margin: 0">
  <div style="height: 100%; width: 100%; display: flex;">
      <div class="container"style="width: 200px; height: 100%; overflow-x: scroll; background-color: #efefef;">
          <div class="scrollable-list-item">scrollable list item</div>
          <div class="scrollable-list-item scrollable-list-item-active">scrollable list item</div>
          <div class="scrollable-list-item">scrollable list item</div>
          <div class="scrollable-list-item">scrollable list item</div>
          <div class="scrollable-list-item">scrollable list item</div>
          <div class="scrollable-list-item">scrollable list item</div>
          <div class="scrollable-list-item">scrollable list item</div>
          <div class="scrollable-list-item">scrollable list item</div>
          <div class="scrollable-list-item">scrollable list item</div>
          <div class="scrollable-list-item">scrollable list item</div>
          <div class="scrollable-list-item">scrollable list item</div>
          <div class="scrollable-list-item">scrollable list item</div>
          <div class="scrollable-list-item">scrollable list item</div>
          <div class="scrollable-list-item">scrollable list item</div>
          <div class="scrollable-list-item">scrollable list item</div>
          <div class="scrollable-list-item">scrollable list item</div>
          <div class="scrollable-list-item">scrollable list item</div>
          <div class="scrollable-list-item">scrollable list item</div>
          <div class="scrollable-list-item">scrollable list item</div>
          <div class="scrollable-list-item">scrollable list item</div>
          <div class="scrollable-list-item">scrollable list item</div>
          <div class="scrollable-list-item">scrollable list item</div>
          <div class="scrollable-list-item">scrollable list item</div>
          <div class="scrollable-list-item">scrollable list item</div>
          <div class="scrollable-list-item">scrollable list item</div>
          <div class="scrollable-list-item">scrollable list item</div>
          <div class="scrollable-list-item">scrollable list item</div>
          <div class="scrollable-list-item">scrollable list item</div>
      </div>
      <div>content</div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Applying `scrollbar-width: none` to the container div did not work for me.

I tried `::-webkit-scrollbar { display: none;}` and this did the trick. This removes the scrollbar from the view while keeping its functionality and does not add any unnecessary padding.

Answer (score -1):

You got this extra padding because you can't control the scrollbar, it's an element generated by your web browser.

The only solution to get over this problem is to disable the default scrollbar and use a custom one like *SimpleBar*.
This way you will have full control over the scrollbar and it will be the same accross every web browser.